# A non well formed numeric value encountered in with dates

Tags: php, class, numeric

im getting this message all over the place and cant figure out why its happening, any help would be appreciated.

the error message is A non well formed numeric value encountered in

the code where im getting the error message is  `$stmt->bindParam("ss",$delete, $dateMaker->getTodayDate());`

the class im calling is set up very simple `return date("Y-m-d");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 3rd parameter of bindParam must be integer not a date

```
 public PDOStatement::bindParam ( 
      string|int $param , 
      mixed &$var , 
     int $type = PDO::PARAM_STR , 
     int $maxLength = 0 , mixed $driverOptions = null ) : bool
```

https://www.php.net/manual/fr/pdostatement.bindparam.php

Comment: doesn't make since, seeing as i only have 2 parameters but it helped, ty

Comment: Your 3rd parameter is $dateMaker->getTodayDate()